# Simplify Legendre Polynomial times a power

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials, legendre-polynomials

How do I simplify

$x^n P_n\left(\frac{y} {x} \right) $

where $P_n$ is a Legendre polynomial and

$x^2=y^2+a$?

I further want to take derivatives with respect to $y$ and $a$.

Comment: Please define _simplify_.

Comment: To remove the x dependence